# How can I get the Building Tools add-on to work at Blender 3.0?

Tags: add-on

Building Tools worked fine for me until I upgraded to Blender 3.0. Now when I try to us it I get a long error message about Python script. Should I give up regarding Building Tools and move on with life?

Comment: That's a third-party addon so not really suitable for questions here. However, do you have the latest version [1.0.9](https://github.com/ranjian0/building_tools/releases/tag/v1.0.9) which says it's for Blender 3.0 and was released in November last year?

Comment: I am very happy that you provided me with the link, and I was thinking that it is a free third-party tool and not one I payed for. Still, I will try to ask the provider directly next time in a similar situation.

Comment: I've never actually used it or had occasion to try it myself but a couple of minutes on Google showed the latest version number. If you do find that an addon doesn't work when Blender is updated, it's always worth expanding its entry in Preferences > Addons and seeing if there's a direct link to the web site where you may find an updated version.